# How can I add a "share" option to an iOS/iPhone or Android image gallery?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile

I'm trying to add either a "share" option to iOS or Android phone galleries, or else another menu option that will perform the same task. I would like to start with iOS if it is possible. For example, if you go to your image gallery on an iPhone or Android phone, there is a share button, and you can choose Email, Picasa, Facebook, Twitter, etc depending on the phone. I need to add something like that to share it to my own web site or app.

If anyone has an idea of even a starting point to start reading that would be helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on iOS, you can use ShareKit:

[ShareKit : Drop-in Share Features for all iOS Apps](http://getsharekit.com/)

on Android, use ACTION_SEND:

[Sharing content in Android using ACTION_SEND Intent](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent)

Comment: These are both useful starting points, but it seems to add the options into your own app - do you know if the new share options will carry over to the image gallery default app?

Comment: I'm not sure about Android, but on iOS, no they won't - you cannot alter other apps in any way.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 6, you can use this approach:

```
NSString* someText = self.textView.text;
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = 
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare 
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

But on iOS 5, Sharekit is the only way as far as i know.