# Cocos2d-x sharing on iOS using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

Im trying to implement sharing as described here: [How can I add a "share" option to an iOS/iPhone or Android image gallery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829942/how-can-i-add-a-share-option-to-an-ios-iphone-or-android-image-gallery)

```
NSString* someText = self.textView.text;
NSArray* dataToShare = @[someText];  // ...or whatever pieces of data you want to share.

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController = 
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare 
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

I'm running this code using after a MenuItem has been clicked, I have an `mm` file which allows me to execute obj-c code.

The problem is with the `self` operator, my class is not derived from the iOS classes, what should I use instead?

Comment: Can you [integrate your cocos-stuff into a UIKit application](http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/24983791554/mixing-cocos2d-x-uikit)?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in cocos2d v3 is just to use the `CCDirector` like this:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Cocos2d-x (version < 2.2) based iOS app I once wrote I had an Objective-C class AppController 
which inherits `UIApplicationDelegate` :

```
@interface AppController : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

and has a member:

```
RootViewController    *viewController;
```

In the method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the viewController 
is initialized and at the end the control is passed over to the cocos2d application class:

```
cocos2d::CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
```

Then there is the C++ class which inherits `CCApplication` :

```
class  AppDelegate : private cocos2d::CCApplication
```

which implements the method `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` which initializes the usual Cocos2d-x stuff and then calls `CCDirector::runWithScene()`.
I guess your app has a similar architecture.
You should try to pass on the `RootViewController` pointer and then call

```
[viewController presentViewController: animated:];
```